# ASIO without RTTI

Tags: c++, g++, boost-asio, c++20, rtti

I'm trying to use ASIO (1.24) without rtti but I always get undefined reference errors.
So I made a simple test program which reproduces the problem:

Main.cpp:

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#define ASIO_HEADER_ONLY
#define ASIO_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#define ASIO_NO_TYPEID
#include "asio.hpp"

int main()
{
    asio::io_context io;

    return 0;
}
```

When it gets compiled with

```
g++-12 -o Test -std=c++20 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -I../libs/Asio/1.24.0/include Main.cpp
```

I get

```
undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<std::system_error>(std::system_error const&)'
undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<asio::invalid_service_owner>(asio::invalid_service_owner const&)'
undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<asio::service_already_exists>(asio::service_already_exists const&)'
```

Is there something I missed? How can I get this to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Boost documentation states](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/exception/doc/configuration_macros.html) that you need to supply a `throw_exception` function if you compile without exception support:

> This macro disables exception handling in Boost, **forwarding all exceptions to a user-defined non-template version of `boost::throw_exception`**. However, unless `BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE` is also defined, users can still examine the exception object for any data added at the point of the throw, or use `boost::diagnostic_information` (of course under `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS`, the user-defined `boost::throw_exception` is not allowed to return to the caller.)

I assume this closely translates to standalone Asio